# How do I retrieve json data from a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to understand and use json.  Most examples leave out just enough to leave me hanging, or go into jQuery or ajax which I want to do eventually, but right now, just want to understand the basics of json.  This PHP code seems to be working, but the javascript is not....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Connecting MySQL Server</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Charlie R Chisholm">
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass,dbc);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

    $query = $mysqli->query("select * from codeTable where tableCode='TABLE' order by Description");
    $json = array();
    if($query->num_rows){
        while($tblArray[] = $query->fetch_object()){
        $json['codeTable'][]=$tblArray;
        }
    }
    mysql_close($mysqli);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var tbl = <? echo json_encode($json) ?>;

            // How would I get the Description data in the second row (for example) 
            // the line below is certainly not right                    

    alert(tbl["codeTable"][1].Description); 

</script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and I get this result...

```
{"codeTable":[[{"codeID":"4","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Document Type","Code":"DOCTP","groupCode":"","t1":null,"t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:52:06","chaDate":null}],[{"codeID":"4","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Document Type","Code":"DOCTP","groupCode":"","t1":null,"t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:52:06","chaDate":null},{"codeID":"8","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Images","Code":"IMAGE","groupCode":"","t1":"Upload Doc Name","t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:57:15","chaDate":null}],[{"codeID":"4","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Document Type","Code":"DOCTP","groupCode":"","t1":null,"t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:52:06","chaDate":null},{"codeID":"8","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Images","Code":"IMAGE","groupCode":"","t1":"Upload Doc Name","t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:57:15","chaDate":null},{"codeID":"1","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Note Type","Code":"NTYPE","groupCode":"GENRL","t1":"","t2":"","t3":"","createDate":"2014-03-11 18:26:27","chaDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],[{"codeID":"4","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Document Type","Code":"DOCTP","groupCode":"","t1":null,"t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:52:06","chaDate":null},{"codeID":"8","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Images","Code":"IMAGE","groupCode":"","t1":"Upload Doc Name","t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:57:15","chaDate":null},{"codeID":"1","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Note Type","Code":"NTYPE","groupCode":"GENRL","t1":"","t2":"","t3":"","createDate":"2014-03-11 18:26:27","chaDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"codeID":"5","tableCode":"TABLE","Description":"Projects","Code":"PRJCT","groupCode":"","t1":null,"t2":null,"t3":null,"createDate":"2014-03-28 18:53:14","chaDate":null}]]}
```

...but from here, I know not where I go.  I tried to retrieve information from the tbl variable with several different notation styles, but I seem to get "undefined" or "[object]" or "[object][object]" rather than the data.  Can someone help me understand the syntax I need to be able to retrieve values from the json?  (the alert box is just an example of not knowing what I am doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tbl["codeTable"][1]` is an array, not an object. It doesn't have a `Description` property.

You need to pick one of the items in the array.

`tbl["codeTable"][1][0]`

This is an object which does have a `Description` property.

`tbl["codeTable"][1][0].Description`

---

Alternatively, just don't create the array with one item in it in the first place.

```
while($tblArray[] = $query->fetch_object()){
    $json['codeTable'][]=$tblArray;
}
```

Should be:

```
while($myObject = $query->fetch_object()){
    $json['codeTable'][] = $myObject;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var tbl = <? echo json_encode($json) ?>; 
var content = $.parseJSON(tbl);
$.each(content, function(key, value) {
   alert(key + ": " + value);
});
```